# Building Image Card in React Native

Tags: reactjs, image, react-native, mobile, components

I'm trying to build a simple image card component in React Native and got some problems. This is my component now ([It's available for you on snack](https://snack.expo.io/@menorme/aW1hZ2)):

[image]

- I can't find a way to set border only on the top of the image on the card, keeping the bottom border flat.

Desired form:
[image]

- The Image component doesn't seen to be rendered from the top showing the model's face, instead it's getting centered showing her body.

Here it's the original image for comparison:

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use this code. Added `overflow: "hidden"` to the `View` and removed `borderRadius` for `Image`. Tested in IOS.

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { Text, View, Image } from "react-native";


export default class RootComponent extends React.Component {

  render() {
    return (
      <View style={{ flex: 1, alignItems: "center", justifyContent: "center" }}>
        <View style={{ backgroundColor: "#eee", borderRadius: 10, overflow: "hidden" }}>
          <View>
            <Image
              source={require("./assets/h4.jpg")}
              style={{
                height: 135,
                width: 155
              }}
            />
          </View>
          <View style={{ padding: 10, width: 155 }}>
            <Text>Title</Text>
            <Text style={{ color: "#777", paddingTop: 5 }}>
              Description of the image
            </Text>
          </View>
        </View>
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

By removing the height from the `<Image>` and setting it in its parent view, the image will be shown from the top.

```
  <View style={{ flex: 1, alignItems: "center", justifyContent: "center" }}>
    <View style={{ backgroundColor: "#eee", borderRadius: 10, overflow: 'hidden' }}>
      <View style={{ height: 135, width: 155, overflow: 'hidden' }}>
        <Image
          source={require("./assets/h4.jpg")}
          style={{
            width: 155
          }}
        />
      </View>
      <View style={{ padding: 10, width: 155 }}>
        <Text>Title</Text>
        <Text style={{ color: "#777", paddingTop: 5 }}>
          Description of the image
        </Text>
      </View>
    </View>
  </View>
```

Comment: Since it was two questions inside one I've selected the first posted to be correct. But this is correct too since it will render the image from top. Thank you !

Answer (score 0):

You can directly do it with `borderTopLeftRadius` and `borderTopRightRadius` in a `Card`.

```
<Card
    containerStyle={styles.boxCon}
    featuredTitle={title}
    image={{
      uri: urlToImage
    }}
    imageStyle={{ borderTopLeftRadius: 10, borderTopRightRadius: 10 }}
>

const styles = {
  boxCon: {
   margin: 15,
   marginHorizontal: 10,
   marginBottom: 17.5,
   borderColor: '#FFFFFF',
   shadowColor: '#000',
   shadowOffset: { width: 0, height: 2 },
   shadowOpacity: 0.3,
   shadowRadius: 5,
   elevation: 5,
   borderRadius: 10
  }
};
```